# Rails 5 image_tag only displaying 1px when referencing external image

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to figure out why when I use

```
<%= image_tag @user.image %>
```

Nothing is displayed.

```
@user.image = 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/816045440361709573/v2Yc3Lyz_normal.jpg'
```

My environments is:

- Mac OSX v10.11.6
- Rails v5.0.1
- Ruby v2.3.1p112
- rbenv v1
- Pow v0.5.0 - for web server

When I look at source I can see that the link is rendering correctly:

```
<img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/816045440361709573/v2Yc3Lyz_normal.jpg" alt="V2yc3lyz normal">
```

And if I go to the link I can see the picture, there are no CSS hiding it.  This happens on a completely blank completely new app as well

[image]

Also I have noticed that when I look at network tab in chrome I can see that it returns the link as data base64:

[image]

If i add width and hight I still get blank image:
[image]

**UPDATE:**

Its Chrome doing something stupid, if I open in safari, it works!  I am using Chrome Version 55.0.2883.95

Comment: Have you tried to declare `width` and `height` explicitly to see what happens?

Comment: Yeah tried that, which lead to my update above

Comment: i am trying to using like this way <%=image_tag @user.image , width: '230px', height: '123px' %>  in my local working fine.

Comment: ok well then that tells me its something about my environment, as I did and I will attach screenshot and still nothing

Comment: Try to open page in incognito mode Cmd+Shift+N. Maybe any extension are doing something wrong. And try to open other an image, without https.

Comment: Extension called "Disconnect", disabled that and it worked, thanks alex